# how I can compare two curved lines in two pictures?

Tags: image-processing, curve

I have 2 picture that there is two line,I want to compare there two curved line and know how much they are similar together...I use Mathlab for programming and also use Image process package.

Thank's in advance
[image]
[Photo Album](https://web.archive.org/web/20181112054310/http://www.photoalbum-2day.com:80/)

[URL=http://www.photoalbum-2day.com/image.php?i=31873-jpg][IMG=http://www.photoalbum-2day.com/images/000/031/873-t.jpg][/IMG][/URL]

Comment: Before I'll be able to help you can you please tell me if there any scaling involved or no scaling? and all what we have is just rotation and likely-hood?

Comment: we dont have any scaling for this issue,just we need to separate the shapes and rotate them and compare them that how many present they are look like,I already separate them but I dont have any idea about to compare them :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this question is still open, I would advice you to have a look at [Fréchet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distance), or [Hausdorff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) distance measures. These two are measures of distance between two curves.